Doable moves only - Infinite Loop
I am trying to run a simple test case which has 2 Shifts(PlanningEntity) and 2 Employees (PlanningVariable)
On running my test case , its running in infinite loop with below logs

NORMAL_OUTPUT{  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE FilteringMoveSelector:133 -
Move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b}) filtered out by a
selection filter (Doable moves only). []
NORMAL_OUTPUT{  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE FilteringMoveSelector:133 -
Move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b}) filtered out by a
selection filter (Doable moves only). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTv  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE LocalSearchDecider:128 -
Move index (0), score (0hard/0soft), accepted (true), move
(com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTÇ  2024-07-23 15:30:12 DEBUG DefaultLocalSearchPhase:136


LS step (4393290), time spent (487837), score (0hard/0soft),     best score (0hard/0soft), accepted/selected move count (1/1), picked



move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTy  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE FilteringMoveSelector:133 -
Move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}) filtered out by a
selection filter (Doable moves only). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTv  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE LocalSearchDecider:128 -
Move index (0), score (0hard/0soft), accepted (true), move
(com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTÇ  2024-07-23 15:30:12 DEBUG DefaultLocalSearchPhase:136


LS step (4393291), time spent (487838), score (0hard/0soft),     best score (0hard/0soft), accepted/selected move count (1/1), picked



move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUT6  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE LocalSearchDecider:128 -
Move index (0), score (0hard/0soft), accepted (true), move
(com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b ->
com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUT‡  2024-07-23 15:30:12 DEBUG DefaultLocalSearchPhase:136


LS step (4393292), time spent (487838), score (0hard/0soft),     best score (0hard/0soft), accepted/selected move count (1/1), picked



move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@ea28db8b ->
com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}). []
NORMAL_OUTPUTy  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE FilteringMoveSelector:133 -
Move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f} <->
com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@d1e5fb82
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}) filtered out by a
selection filter (Doable moves only). []
NORMAL_OUTPUT9  2024-07-23 15:30:12 TRACE FilteringMoveSelector:133 -
Move (com.business.shift.entity.ShiftOccurrence@ec8c4d30
{com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f ->
com.business.shift.EmployeeShiftDetails@8f27f1f}) filtered out by a
selection filter (Doable moves only). []

To debug the issue, below is what I tried

If my understanding is correct, this issue could happen when constraints are tight this could happen, hence I commented all the constraints

Made sure that the problem is not complex with simple data [only 2 Shifts and 2 Employees ]

Enabled trace logs to debug , to see if i get any information


Questions I have is

How to find out the cause of inifinite loop
Though i have set timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit=1m why doesnt the solver terminate ?
Under what condition does solver get into infinite loop

Below is the simple test data that I am running - 2 ShiftOccurrences(PlanningEntity) and 2 EmployeeShiftDetails (PlanningVariable)



How to find out the cause of inifinite loop

There is no infinite loop. The solver is properly making steps and isn't stuck in any of them. It's accepting and selecting moves. This means your termination conditions aren't working.

Though I have set timefold.solver.termination.spent-limit=1m why doesn't the solver terminate ?

Without any executable code to run, there is no way to answer your question. Maybe there is a typo somewhere? Maybe the application.properties file cannot be found? There's many possible reasons.
This may be one reason why your question is downvoted. (Although it wasn't me who voted it down.)

Under what condition does solver get into infinite loop

It doesn't. See above.
Suggestion: If your entities and facts implemented toString() instead of relying on a default one, maybe the solver output would have been more useful. (Yet another possible reason why your question may be downvoted.)
